# Show div on multiple clicks using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the best way to show one div only when 3 divs have been clicked?

Currently, what I have done works, but I'm looking for a simpler way - particularly if there are more than 3 divs that need to validated:

```
var div1Clicked= false;

$("#div1").click(function () {
    div1Clicked = true;
    validation();
}); 

var div2Clicked= false;

$("#div2").click(function () {
    div2Clicked = true;
    validation();
}); 

var div3Clicked= false;

$("#div3").click(function () {
    div3Clicked = true;
    validation();
});

function validation(){
    if ((div1Clicked) && (div2Clicked) && (div3Clicked)) {
        $("#showDiv").show();
    } else {
        $("#showDiv").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and JS which you have tried

Comment: You will have to explain better, exactly what do you want? Also, show us what have you done till now?

Comment: Just a simple code, a little bit a hack, it should work.

    var checkallbuttonsclick = [];
    $(".buttonclass").click(function(){ aa = JSON.stringify($(this)); 
    if(checkallbuttonsclick.indexOf(aa) == -1){ checkallbuttonsclick.push(aa);
    if(checkallbuttonsclick.length == 4){ $("#otherdiv").show(); } } });

Comment: I've added the code now, just to clarify what I want to happen is that when 3 different divs are clicked I want a div to appear.

Comment: Hi Donald, I wrote a working answer for this, but there may be a better way of doing what you're trying to accomplish in general, i.e. triggering something based on 1 or more actions (that might be the reason for some of the down votes). Maybe you can elaborate on the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to use a class as the selector for your click function and to designate which divs have been clicked. For example, you could add a `clickable` class to each div you want to check. You could then have a generic click function for any `clickable` div and add a `clicked` class to that div once the function is called:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="clickable"></div>
<div id="div2" class="clickable clicked"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(".clickable").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    if ($(".clickable:not(.clicked)").length === 0) {
        $('#showDiv').show(); 
    }
});
```

As shown above, the jQuery to check if any clickable divs have not been clicked is:

```
if ($(".clickable:not(.clicked)").length === 0)
```

You can give it a try here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6vnh9ko/2/)

There are many possible solutions, though.
Hope that helps!